# Hibernate Parent Child Same Table Error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a problem with Hibernate using a parent child relationship in the same table.  I can do selects and inserts but I can not delete.  I wrote a JUnit test to see what was going on and found some odd behavior.

Here is how I define my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `productId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `parentProductId` bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PARENTPRODUCT` FOREIGN KEY (`parentProductId`) REFERENCES `product` (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My Product class looks like :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    private Long productId;
    private String name;
    private Product parentProduct;
    private Set<Product> children;
    private List<CustomerProduct> productCustomers;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(Long productId, String name) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentProductId")
    public Product getParentProduct() {
        return parentProduct;
    }

    public void setParentProduct(Product parentProduct) {
        this.parentProduct = parentProduct;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentProduct", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Product> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Product> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    public List<CustomerProduct> getProductCustomers() {
        return productCustomers;
    }

    public void setProductCustomers(List<CustomerProduct> productCustomers) {
        this.productCustomers = productCustomers;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Product other = (Product) obj;
        if (this.productId != other.productId
            && (this.productId == null || !this.productId.equals(other.productId)))
                return false;
        if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 31 * hash + name.length();
        hash = 31 * hash + (name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [productId=" + productId + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

I wrote a few JUnit tests which are:

```
@Test
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void getProductNoChildren() {
    Product p = productService.getProductById(Long.parseLong("1"));
    assertNotNull(p);
    assertTrue(p.getName().equals("Test"));
    assertNull(p.getParentProduct());
    assertTrue(p.getChildren().size() == 0);
}

@Test
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void getProductWithChildren() {
    Product p = productService.getProductById(Long.parseLong("10"));
    assertNotNull(p);
    assertTrue(p.getName().equals("Test_2"));
    assertNull(p.getParentProduct());
    assertTrue(p.getChildren().size() > 0);
}

@Test
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void getProductWithParent() {
    Product p = productService.getProductById(Long.parseLong("20"));
    assertNotNull(p);
    assertTrue(p.getName().equals("Test_3"));
    assertNotNull(p.getParentProduct());
    assertTrue(p.getParentProduct().getProductId() == Long.parseLong("2"));
    assertTrue(p.getChildren().size() == 0);
}
```

The first 2 tests pass.  The 3rd always fails with a NullPointerException on the 2nd line of the hashcode method.  Says name is null.  I verified this only happens when a parentProductId is set.  I can not figure out why this is happening.  The name should never be null.  Do I have an error in the way I defined the hibernate annotations for my class?

Here is my stacktrace if anyone is interested.....

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.symmetry.security.model.Product.hashCode(Product.java:145)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:372)
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:200)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:352)
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:261)
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:246)
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:219)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.endCollectionLoad(Loader.java:1005)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:993)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:857)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1038)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:630)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438)
at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:139)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:982)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:857)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
at com.symmetry.security.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractDao.findById(HibernateAbstractDao.java:52)
at com.symmetry.security.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractDao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b227fdff.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at com.symmetry.security.dao.hibernate.HibernateProductDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$415fcf17.findById(<generated>)
at com.symmetry.security.service.ProductServiceImpl.getProductById(ProductServiceImpl.java:42)
at com.symmetry.security.service.ProductServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8b8f4a88.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at com.symmetry.security.service.ProductServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b032e753.getProductById(<generated>)
at com.symmetry.security.service.ProductServiceImplUnitTest.getProductWithParent(ProductServiceImplUnitTest.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a Property access to let Hibernate use setters/getters to manage object. But in your hashcode() & equals() methods you use fields directly which bypasses Hibernate.

Moreover if you're accessing in equals() method fields of another class directly, this will fail if that object is a proxy because it will try to access the field of the proxy, while the real object itself is another field of that proxy. So in this case you should use getter as well.

Comment: So should i change everything to this.getName where name is being used?  Can you give an exmaple if you meant otherwise?  Thanks

Comment: Yap, getXxx() methods should be used instead of fields directly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses but I am getting the same NullPointerException even when using getXXX methods in equals and hashcode.  Any other ideas or thoughts?